# GCP: how to add permissions to an existing service account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am working on project to automate deployment of Google Cloud Functions.

I tried running this just on the standard cloud build system and always got errors ... now just trying to remove the service account I was using is giving me an error:

[image: the error messsage I'm getting this morning]

I understand there's probably a way to do this with the cloudbuild API, but I don't know that as well ... I'd really appreciate help from anyone out there who's done this before.

Thanks.

Comment: You, the current logged user, do not have the permission to update the trigger. Be sure to have this role on the current project: `roles/cloudbuild.builds.editor`

Comment: I just verified that role to be in the project but when I try to save I get the same error message ... I am still not sure what I'm doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: I am trying Gcloud CLI commands .. got the first one to work but still can't change the trigger in the UI and when I try the CLI command:  gcloud alpha builds triggers update "Push-to-lig-cloud" \
    --project="clearspring-production" \
    --repo="clearspring/lig-priving-v2-cloudfunc" \
    --branch-pattern= "kubernetes$" \
    --build-config= "/cloudbuild.yaml"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that Google Cloud Functions are not supported in all regions, and certainly not us-central1, which is the region I had been specifying. I had missed this on the (wrapped) error message I had been seeing. ... the only thing visible on the screen was "403 -- permission denied" and I had missed the wrapped information on the error message.

I never did get the UI to add permissions to the service account ... I had to do this with the gcloud CLI ...

I first tried a bunch of huge lists of permissions, but once I got the message that the region was wrong, there were only three that were required:

1. LogsWriter
2. Cloud Build Service Account

There were also a number of non-zero returns in the codebase, several of which I fixed but one I couldn't find.

There is a Google Cloud product called CloudTrace that doesn't come with GCP accounts by default (apparrently) as I kept trying to run it and getting turned back on the "get one free" page.

I hope this is helpful; please let me know if you have any questions about this.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to grant the `roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator` role to the Service account.

And also very the below permissions.

https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/securing-builds/configure-user-specified-service-accounts#permissions

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that we had to change from trying the methods we were using to just giving up because of some bugs we found:

(1) There's a bug in the UI : when I try to create a new trigger for the Cloud Build section, it says "you don't have permission"

I can create a new trigger, but that means every time I have to try anything mew I need a new trigger.

(2) Despite working on this for months: getting google Cloud functions deployed indiviudally ... we gave up on this as Not Doable (with current GCP software anyway)

Our latest try is to go back and try deploying with GKE, which we've gotten going in the past ...

Questions?